# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

I tried restarting the Mysql server but its not working for me. I am sure the server is running and the permissions on the folder /var/lib/mysql/ are correct (777).

When i tried to open the file mysql.sock, its giving me an error saying the file may be corrupt.

Please help me to log on to the mysql server.

Comment: Question : Is mysqld still running but you cannot connect?

Comment: Please run `service mysql status` and post the output of that command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: Make sure that the owner of `/var/lib/mysql` and its files and subdirectories is `mysql` user of `mysql` group

to do that run the following command:

```
chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql/*
```

Second: change write permissions to rwxr-xr-x (755) for mysql directory, and all its files and subdirectories, by running the following command:

```
chmod 755 -R /var/lib/mysql/*
```

now start mysql service

```
service mysql start
```

Comment: Did everything you suggested, but could not find the mysql.sock file in the folder you specified

Comment: Please tell the location of socket file by seeing from my.cnf.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem and solved with:

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db/

Answer (score 0):

For me, *stopping docker* in the background was the solution. Nothing else worked, and nothing pointer to docker except when running

```
lsof -i TCP:3306
```

and then trying to

```
kill <process_id>
```

the error from docker popped up so I knew Docker was having some background mysql listeners.

Answer (score -2):

Just do it, it worked to me...

> mysql.server start
>
> [mysql -u "username" -p "password"]

[image]